# Jetty configuration in GoogleAppEngine Standard

Tags: google-app-engine, jetty

I tried `<env-var name="JETTY_PROPERTIES" value="httpConfig.requestCookieCompliance=RFC2965,jetty.httpConfig.responseCookieCompliance=RFC2965"/>` in *appengine-web.xml* hoping that the advice in https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/dev-jetty9 would work for standard environment too. No luck. How do I set Jetty configuration in Google App Engine Standard?

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to mess with the cookie compliance modes, as you will break cookie behavior on many browsers, many intermediaries, and even the Google Front End.   What are you struggling with?  Please detail the cookie behaviors you have now, and what you want it to behave like. (as what you are looking for might not be compliance mode configuration)  Also for what HTTP User-Agents (HTTP Clients, Browsers, etc) that you want your solution to work with.

Comment: Proxying an old website. So is it true that it is only possible to set jetty config with "flexible", but not with "standard"? Or is there some way to do this with "standard" too?

Comment: If you are proxying, you will likely have to parse and rewrite the cookies in your proxy for any meaningful success.   The old Cookie syntax from RFC2965 (that Jetty produces) will result in rejected / dropped Cookies on many browsers today.  That compliance mode only really exists for internal (not over the internet) communication between legacy (non-browser) http clients and legacy webapps.

Comment: Example: Use of RFC2965 today will result in dropped Cookies on modern browsers (the browser will just quietly ignore the cookie and never send it to the server)

Comment: Can someone please confirm that this is possible only in flexible but not in standard?

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt btw jetty's (as used by GAE) RFC6265 enforcement is too strict for practical use. See for example the leniencies that Tomcat allows.
In any case that is off topic. My question was about GAE, not jetty. I'm wondering if GAE standard allows setting Jetty config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The environment variable `JETTY_PROPERTIES` was introduced for GAE Flexible Environment.

It doesn't exist for the older GAE Standard Environment.

Depending on your runtime, you might still be on Jetty 9.3.x, in which case those properties you are attempting to set do not even exist there (they were introduced in Jetty 9.4.9.v20180320)

For GAE Flexible Runtime see ...

See: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/jetty-runtime

The bash script responsible for reading that `<env-var>` is `50-jetty.bash` -

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/jetty-runtime/blob/master/jetty9/src/main/docker/50-jetty.bash#L36-L38

## The behavior of Cookie Compliance in Jetty codebase

⚠️ There is no RFC2109 support, as it contains far too many security issues to be safe.

### RFC6265 - Default Behavior

#### Generation

(eg: Server-side `Set-Cookie` response header, or Client-side `Cookie` request header)

- Name must be valid [per RFC2616 token rules](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.35.v20201120/jetty-http/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/http/Syntax.java#L32-L82) (US-ASCII, 7-bit, **excluding** control characters, and separators)
- Value must be valid [per RFC6265 value rules](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.35.v20201120/jetty-http/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/http/Syntax.java#L84-L141) (US-ASCII, 7-bit, **excluding** control characters, whitespace, DQUOTE `"`, comma `,`, semicolon `;`, and backslash `\`)
- Does not generate `Version=#` entry
- Does not generate `Comment=` entry
- Does not generate "$" entries (like `$Version`, `$Domain`, `$Port`, and `$Version` entries)
- Generates the following entries

  - `Path`
  - `Domain`
  - `Expires`
  - `Max-Age`
  - `Secure`
  - `HttpOnly`
  - `SameSite`

#### Parsing

(eg: Server-side `Cookie` request header, or Client-side `Set-Cookie` response header)

- Lenient parser based on industry recommendations for safe Cookie parsing behaviors - RFC6265 - Example parsing behavior: [CookieCutterLenientTest](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.35.v20201120/jetty-server/src/test/java/org/eclipse/jetty/server/CookieCutterLenientTest.java)
- Name must be valid [per RFC2616 token rules](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.35.v20201120/jetty-http/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/http/Syntax.java#L32-L82) (US-ASCII, 7-bit, **excluding** control characters, and separators) - will REJECT cookie if fails (meaning the Cookie doesn't show up in resulting Cookie list)
- Value must be valid [per RFC6265 value rules](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.35.v20201120/jetty-http/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/http/Syntax.java#L84-L141) (US-ASCII, 7-bit, **excluding** control characters, whitespace, DQUOTE `"`, comma `,`, semicolon `;`, and backslash `\`) - will REJECT cookie if fails
- Value allows DQUOTE during parsing, but it must be supported by matching DQUOTE at end of value. - will REJECT cookie if fails (meaning the Cookie doesn't show up in resulting Cookie list)
- Ignores "$" named entries (like `$Version`, `$Domain`, `$Port`, and `$Version` entries)
- Does not allow more then 1 cookie declaration per `Cookie` header (the ancient "comma delim" approach from HTTP/1.0 days)

### RFC2965 - Alternate Behavior

#### Generation

(eg: Server-side `Set-Cookie` response header, or Client-side `Cookie` request header)

- Name must be valid [per RFC2109 rules](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.35.v20201120/jetty-http/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/http/HttpCookie.java#L258-L284) (US-ASCII, 7-bit, **excluding** control characters, delimiters, DQUOTE, comma, semi-colon, backslash, space, and horizontal tab)
- Name will be surrounded by DQUOTE if delimiters are present. (⚠️ if delimiters are present here most modern browsers will reject this entire cookie)
- Value must be valid per [RFC2109 value rules](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.35.v20201120/jetty-http/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/http/HttpCookie.java#L258-L284) (US-ASCII, 7-bit, **excluding** control characters, delimiters, DQUOTE, comma, semi-colon, backslash, space, and horizontal tab)
- Value will be surrounded by DQUOTE if delimiters are present. (⚠️ if delimiters are present here most modern browsers will reject this entire cookie)
- Does not generate "$" entries (like `$Version`, `$Domain`, `$Port`, and `$Version` entries)
- ⚠️ Does not generate `SameSite` entry
- Generates the following entries

  - `Version`
  - `Path`
  - `Domain`
  - `Expires`
  - `Max-Age`
  - `Secure`
  - `HttpOnly`
  - `Comment`

#### Parsing

(eg: Server-side `Cookie` request header, or Client-side `Set-Cookie` response header)

- Name must be valid [per RFC2109 token rules](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.35.v20201120/jetty-http/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/http/Syntax.java#L32-L82) (US-ASCII, 7-bit, **excluding** control characters, and separators) - any violation will result in unpredictable results (like splitting a cookie at the wrong delimiter)
- Value must be valid [per RFC6265 value rules](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.35.v20201120/jetty-http/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/http/Syntax.java#L84-L141) (US-ASCII, 7-bit, **excluding** control characters, whitespace, DQUOTE `"`, comma `,`, semicolon `;`, and backslash `\`)  - any violation will result in unpredictable results (like splitting a cookie at the wrong delimiter)
- Value allows DQUOTE during parsing, but it must be supported by matching DQUOTE at end of value. - any violation will result in unpredictable results (like splitting a cookie at the wrong delimiter)
- Parses "$" named entries (like `$Version`, `$Domain`, `$Port`, and `$Version` entries)

  - Note: `$Port` is reported in the Comment of the resulting parsed Cookie.
- Allows more then 1 cookie declaration per `Cookie` header (the ancient "comma delim" approach from HTTP/1.0 days)
- ⚠️ Does not parse `SameSite` entry